# Encrypt Web.Config value in packaged ASP.NET solution

Tags: asp.net, encryption, configuration, web-config, configuration-files

We are selling a web application to a client, and it includes some 3rd party components. These components require licensing keys to work, which we have stored in the web.config. As we are not selling the source code or the license we need to encrypt that value somehow.

No I know that you can use aspnet_regiis to encrypt section of the web.config, but my understanding is that this done on the host machine and uses the unique machine ID to do the encrypting. That means I can only do the encrypting *after* the client deploys the web app.

Since, we have no control over the deployment part we need to encrypt this value beforehand. In essence, we need it encrypted when we hand over the app to the client.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you certain you have the correct licensing arrangement with the vendor?  If you have a license that allows you to sell an application with embedded 3rd party components, the component vendor should be providing the authentication solution.

Comment: The license keys should be the property of the client and not yours, and hence irrelevant. Distributing your own or in-house license keys is a bad idea.

Comment: @mellamokb - I'm not the legal department, but they assure me that this is the case.

Comment: @SystemDown - Now that I think about it, we have a similar situation in one of our applications used in our customer base.  We have the license key just embedded in the source code actually, and if our customers really wanted to, they could use .Net reflector and get the key.  I don't know what a good solution is really.

Comment: @mellamokb - Yeah, that was my first thought as well. I know some obfuscaters can hide (encrypt?) plain text. It's an option I'm exploring.

Comment: I'm thinking you almost need to implement your own license key, that is used to authenticate to a web service hosted on your premises, which then returns the 3rd-party app license keys to the client system to use (so the values can only be retrieved over the web service, they're not stored anywhere on client machine).  We have a forum software that works in a similar way, I think on App_Start it validates our license key against their server and stores auth in an application cache.  It doesn't bar using memory reading techniques or such to hack it, but it should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the ProtectedConfigurationProvider when you run the command to not use the default encryption mechanism which uses the machine key, but will use a custom key container for encryption. One of the ProtectedConfigurationProvider is RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider and the command would be as shown below. Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx) & [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.rsaprotectedconfigurationprovider.aspx) for details.

```
aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/SampleApplication" -prov "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"
```

Comment: You still have the problem of distributing the key used for RSA encryption.  Technically, if the user has a way to access that key, they can perform the same decryption manually to read the contents of web.config.